# Using Dart's call() method with generics

Tags: generics, dart

I'm trying to write a class which can be called like a function, using generics like so:

```dart
typedef T FooFunction<T>(T input);

class Foo<T> {
  final FooFunction fooFunction;

  Converter(FooFunction<T> this.fooFunction);

  T call(T input) => this.fooFunction(input);

  static final Foo<String> stringFoo = new Foo<String>((String input) => input.trim());

  static final Foo<int> intFoo = new Foo<int>((int input) => input * -1);
}
```

And I am trying to call it like so:

```
String bar = Foo.stringFoo('  Hello World     ');
int baz = Foo.intFoo('5');
```

This code works fine if I remove all the type hinting, but with the type hinting in there, the analyzer is complaining that "An argument of type 'String' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'T'" and that "A value of type 'T' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'String'." It's clear that what's happening here is that the analyzer is seeing the `T` type in the definition of `Foo.call` and interpreting it literally, rather than in the context of the generic type.

If I change my calls to the following:

```
String bar = Foo.stringFoo.fooFunction('  Hello World     ');
int baz = Foo.intFoo.fooFunction('5');
```

so that they are no longer using the `call` method, the analyzer understands what's happening just fine.

Am I doing something wrong in how I'm declaring the `call` method? Is there a way to use the `call` method while maintaining the proper type hinting and static analysis the same as if I were to call the method directly? Or am I doing everything right and I just need to submit a bug report to the Dart devs?

Comment: I think there is a bug in the code. The line `static final Foo<String> stringFoo = (String input) => input.trim();` assignes a function to a static field typed as `Foo<String>`. Should it be `static final Foo<String> stringFoo = new Foo<String>((String input) => input.trim());`? (It doesn't explain the error message, though).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an bug in the analyzer. The simple following test produce no warnings or hints from the analyzer (although the execution fails) :

```dart
class F<T> {
  T call(T t) => t;
}

main() {
  final f = new F<int>();
  f('Fail');
}
```

The VM throw the following error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 't'.

You should [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new).